# Writing a POST request using a jersey client

Tags: java, json, post, jersey, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to implement the following curl request using the jersey client

```
curl  -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -H "Authorization:Bearer 7est6xAiAYrhGmJyUkUKemz2yG_Qqn5RW5FCW1Iq1NLs6khyCMHQ" -X POST -d  @example.json http://api.com/v1/jobs/
```

Here is the **json**

```
{
image_url : abc
}
```

Here is the jersey implementation

```
WebResource resource = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig()).resource("http://api.com/v1/jobs");

WebResource.Builder builder = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
builder.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer 7est6xAiAYrhGmJyUkUKemz2yG_Qqn5RW5FCW1Iq1NLs6khyCMHQ");
String input = "{\"image_url\": \"abc\"}";
ClientResponse output =  builder.post(ClientResponse.class, input);
```

This give me a 400 Bad request error. Where am I going wrong???

Answer (score 1):

You added Accept header 2 times and missed [Content-Type](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType)) in the code. Add below code it will work.

```
builder.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```